# what is wrong in my dart code to calculate age?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart 2.12.2 stable [image: what's wrong with my code]

my code is for age calculation I wrote it from the course and it should work well but when I try it, it shows an error

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i--) {
  try {
  print("Your birth year is : ");
  var birth_year = stdin.readLineSync();
  var age = DateTime.now().year - num.parse("birth_year");
  print("$age");
  } on FormatException {
  print("Invalid");
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You put `birth_year` under quotes, and that is a string, you need to write: `num.parse(birth_year)` instead of `num.parse("birth_year")` to get the value of `birth_year`.